# integrating wordpress blog with zend 2 php framework

Tags: wordpress, zend-framework2

I am working with Zend 2 framework  and i want to integrate wordpress blog with that.

I added wordpress folder into the public folder and now blog is working but when I am click on inner pages 404 error showing. I changed the permalink postname to default then site is working but when on postname showing 404 error.

I already added htaccess in  blog folder but still its showing 404 error. Can anybody let me know how to integrate step by step

Comment: its htaccess problem, try replacing with default htaccess code

Comment: I already do my htaccess file is 
`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress`

Comment: which server you are using apache? and try moving from post to default permalinks, and switch back to post in permalinks

Comment: Would are your arguments against having a 2nd project with WP running on a subdomain (blog.*) instead? Mixing 2 applications for 2 separate purposes, especially WP with its update hell, is going to give you massive headaches.

Comment: yes i have apache server

Answer (score 1):

Follow the simple steps given below to integrate Zend framework with other applications like WordPress, Joomla and other such open source or custom web applications.

i) Setup your Zend framework application as usual.

ii) Set the document root of the Zend application to the public folder within Zend install

iii) Now setup a folder for your wordpress or joomla or custom application. Let us assume that we want to create a custom blog application. Create a folder “blog” within “public” folder. Inside blog folder, create two files – .htaccess and index.php. Code for the two files are given below

**index.php**

```html
<?php
echo “In custom application folder – testing”;
?>
```

**.htaccess**

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule îndex\.php$ - [L] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

You needn’t have to setup custom route within Zend application for its integration with other applications when you follow these simple steps.

Comment: where i add this code in public htaccessor in blog htaccess

Comment: Which htaccess i have 2 htaccess files 1 in public folder of  and 2 in blog folder

and can you please explain step by step

Comment: you put on blog folder

Comment: can you send me complete htaccess file for blog folger